# A way to forward or intercept smtp mail request to localhost?

Tags: email, dns, smtp, jakarta-mail

Wondering if we have options for a failing smtp mail at "localhost" after changing DNS host.

The problem setup is this:

- SMTP mail is being sent from a server, with mail being configured on the server itself. Originally, server was host of DNS domain as well as web app.
- Using JavaMail, a request is sent to "localhost" without any authentication
- The DNS settings have changed, server hosting web app is no longer the "from" email address
- The Java web app cannot be modified and is still sending to "localhost"

Question: Do we have any options?

I'd like to intercept the "localhost" smtp mail request and forward it along to our domain's mail server, with new credentials, but am unsure if that is possible. A stand-alone script to watch for those requests?

We did receive the suggestion to edit our DNS settings on the new hosting and add "MX" and "A" records, but that would require a change of source code, which is not an option at this time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there's no SMTP server running on localhost, and you just want to redirect mail to another mail server without authentication, you could use a simple "proxy/tunnel" using something like the "netcat" program.

If there is an SMTP server running on localhost, you might be able to configure it to forward all messages to your other mail server.

Otherwise, is it possible to change the properties used by JavaMail in your web app, without changing the source code?  For example, do the properties come from a file or from System.getProperties()?

Comment: From what I can tell in this legacy code, a `new Properties` hashmap is created for the `javax.mail.Session`. Only property in there is `mail.smtp.host` which is set to "localhost". Even if I could set a system property to perhaps fill the user and password of my new DNS host, I'm afraid the mail.smtp.host would be over-written by the present line of code.

I think our server host has some SMTP server running and I will see what options exist for that.

Comment: Not wanting to abandon this question, I will choose this as the answer. It was pretty good - though our project's own limitations did not allow full completion.